# Rails: ActiveRecord perform pointless query multiple times over the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my app I have overwritten current_user devise method a bit. The idea is that if certain cookie is present method check the organization by the id inside that cookie and returns owner of this organization instead of regular user:

```
  def current_user
    user = warden.authenticate(scope: :user)
    return nil if user.nil?

    if user.admin? && cookies.key?('mock_admin_login')
      organization = Organization.includes(:creator).find(cookies.encrypted[:mock_admin_login])
      return organization.creator
    end
    user
  end
```

Everything works correct but when I take a look at my console I noticed that Organization query is performed multiple times:

> CACHE Organization Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM
> "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9],
> ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (0.9ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (0.7ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (0.3ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (2.0ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (0.4ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (42.8ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'   CACHE Organization Load (4.5ms)  SELECT
> "organizations".* FROM "organizations" WHERE "organizations"."id" = $1
> LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]   ↳
> app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in
> `current_user'   CACHE User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  [["id", 10]]   ↳ app/controllers/concerns/current_methods_overwritten.rb:11:in` current_user'

Although It might seem like a not big deal but server spends additional 30-40ms to perform this action every time when current_user method is called. Why this query is called so many times instead of one and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why not just axe it? You can either mock authorization through warden or just set the user id in the session, it seems completely pointless.

Comment: I want to let admins to mock that they are creators of the organizations while they posses that cookie. So they store their session but also can pretend they are regular users, as long as they keep cookie in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to memoize the result so that its not reevaluated every time you call `current_user`.

If you look at the helper that devise generates you can see that it does just that:

```
def current_#{mapping}
  @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
end
```

If you want to fix your existing method you want to make sure to memoize the DB calls:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
  if @current_user&.admin? && cookies.key?('mock_admin_login')
    @current_org || = Organization.includes(:creator)
                                    .find(cookies.encrypted[:mock_admin_login])
    @current_user = @current_org.creator
  end
  @current_user
end
```

But you really should implement this as [a custom Warden strategy instead](https://insights.kyan.com/devise-authentication-strategies-a1a6b4e2b891).